# Git: Undo published merge commit and apply another merge of the same commits

Tags: git

One developer merged branch `feature2` into `feature1` and pushed the results, but resolved some merge conflicts incorrectly. I checked out commit `A` from `feature1` and correctly merged in commit `B` from `feature2` (`A` and `B` are the same commits the other developer merged).

I committed the result of the merge to a detached head, and now need to revert the other developer's merge commit and apply my own to `feature1`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The dangerous way:

1) Tag your detached commit, i.e. `git tag temp`.

2) Checkout the `feature1` branch.

3) Use `git reset --hard temp` to move your local copy of the branch to point to your commit.

4) Use `git push -f origin feature1` to overwrite the dodgy version on `origin`.

5) Delete the tag with `git tag -d temp`.

Do all of this carefully, and use `gitk` to see what you're doing. Make sure no-one else is using `origin` at the time. If you're paranoid, tag your colleague's commit as well before you start doing all of this (a good idea in case you mess up).

IMPORTANT: If anyone else has based work on your colleague's merge, think very hard before doing it this way. Everyone will end up needing to rebase on your new commit.

Comment: Is there an option that doesn't involve rewriting history on `origin`?